# how to get Facebook profile picture using Azure AD B2C

Tags: facebook, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

I am using MSAL.js and could successfully sign-in/sign-up users in Azure AD B2C using Facebook as identity provider. The problem is that after sign-in I cannot retrieve user's profile picture.

Azure AD B2C returns an object identifier which has no tie to user's Facebook id.

Comment: Are you using custom policies?

Comment: No, as far as I understand to use custom policies I need to have ad b2c premium account.

Comment: Hi @armache. Custom policies are configuration files that define behaviour for any Azure AD B2C tenant; they don't require a special tenant. Below, I've posted how you can retrieve the picture field for the Facebook user and then issue a picture claim in the ID token, using custom policies.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Using custom policies, you can retrieve the picture field for the Facebook user and then issue a picture claim in the ID token, as follows.

1: Complete the [Azure Active Directory B2C: Get started with custom policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-get-started-custom) steps with one of the social account policies such as the [SocialAndLocalAccounts](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack/tree/master/SocialAndLocalAccounts) one.

2: Declare a "picture" claim in [the extensions file](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack/blob/master/SocialAndLocalAccounts/TrustFrameworkExtensions.xml):

```xml
<ClaimType Id="picture">
  <DisplayName>Picture</DisplayName>
  <DataType>string</DataType>
</ClaimType>
```

3: Add both the "picture" field to the "ClaimsEndpoint" metadata item and the "picture" output claim to the "Facebook-OAUTH" technical profile in [the extensions policy](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack/blob/master/SocialAndLocalAccounts/TrustFrameworkExtensions.xml):

```xml
<ClaimsProvider>
  <DisplayName>Facebook</DisplayName>
  <TechnicalProfiles>
    <TechnicalProfile Id="Facebook-OAUTH">
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="client_id">facebook_clientid</Item>
        <Item Key="scope">email public_profile</Item>
        <Item Key="ClaimsEndpoint">https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=id,first_name,last_name,name,email,picture</Item>
      </Metadata>
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="picture" PartnerClaimType="picture" />
      </OutputClaims>
    </TechnicalProfile>
  </TechnicalProfiles>
</ClaimsProvider>
```

4: Issue the "picture" claim in [the sign-up or sign-in relying party policy](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack/blob/master/SocialAndLocalAccounts/SignUpOrSignin.xml):

```xml
<RelyingParty>
  <DefaultUserJourney ReferenceId="SignUpOrSignIn" />
  <TechnicalProfile Id="PolicyProfile">
    <DisplayName>PolicyProfile</DisplayName>
    <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" />
    <OutputClaims>
      <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" />
      <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
      <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" />
      <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
      <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="picture" />
      <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" PartnerClaimType="sub"/>
      <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProvider" />
    </OutputClaims>
    <SubjectNamingInfo ClaimType="sub" />
  </TechnicalProfile>
</RelyingParty>
```

Comment: the xml mentioned in step 2. i see the similar stuff in Base file not the extension file.
Do i need to put it in Base file ? @armache

Comment: Hi @RaasMasood. You can add the "picture" claim type in either the base or extensions file.

Comment: I am new to this concept so help me. I added it so where should i expect the picture to be? I have a Xamarin test app and AcuireToken call gives me the User object. Where should i expect the picture to be ?

Comment: picture should be a property in Claims section of User Object ? 
will it contain a URL to the picture ? please help

Comment: Hi @RaasMasood The `picture` claim is issued by Azure AD B2C in the ID token to your Xamarin app. Which authentication library are you using with your Xamarin app?

Comment: this didn't work for me and it so sad that none of these implementations has this important feature out of the box.

Comment: Does this method support other IDPs like GitHub or Google?

Comment: @YangLuo were you able to do this for Google?

Comment: @MárioMeyrelles Had you manage to do it with Google, I need age_range, and gender from Google and Facebook